# shutil.copy to a subdir

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

If I am trying to copy files to a subdir, as:

```
dirname = os.path.join(sys.argv[1], optdir)
print("dirname: "+dirname)
if not os.path.exists(dirname):
    os.makedirs(dirname)
shutil.copy(files, dirname)
```

shutil.copy is giving error as:

```
dirname: ./8/opt2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rudra/bin/latres.py", line 84, in <module>
    shutil.copy(files, dirname)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/shutil.py", line 234, in copy
    dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/posixpath.py", line 139, in basename
    i = p.rfind(sep) + 1
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Which is possibly due to     `dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))` in the error msg, so, it is only getting opt2, and not the `./8` part of the dir name.

in this situation, how can I copy files to a `subdir`?

Answer (score 0):

`files` is a list of file names but `copy` only copes a single file. So put it in a loop:

```
for fn in files:
    shutil.copy(fn, dirname)
```